# How to use None as a placeholder for a non optional variable without mypy complaining about it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Going straight to the code:

```
from typing import Optional, List


class Bar:
    pass


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar_list: List[Optional[Bar]]) -> None:
        self.bar_list: List[Bar] = bar_list # mypy will signal an error here

        for i, bar in enumerate(self.bar_list):
            if bar is None:
                self.bar_list[i] = self.__default_bar()

    def __default_bar(self):
        # create default
        pass
```

It makes perfect sense for mypy to do this, however I want to make clear that when using this class `foo.barl_list` should never be expected to have `None` elements, while also providing flexibility of only assigning some custom values and let the constructor add a default to the rest.

So how can I keep this functionality without triggering mypy errors? One way would be to initialize `self.bar_list` as an empty list then append all the values, but that results in list reallocation costs that could be significant in case of a big list, so I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is fundamentally incompatible with a *static* type of `List[Bar]`. However, you can tell the static type checker that you know what you are doing by *casting* the list as a different type. It is up to you to uphold the invariant by indeed replacing each `None` with an actual instance of `Bar`. (To be clear, the type checker cannot help you verify that you have indeed done that.)

```
def __init__(self, bar_list: List[Optional[Bar]]) -> None:
    self.bar_list: List[Bar] = typing.cast(List[Bar], bar_list)

    for i, bar in enumerate(self.bar_list):
        if bar is None:
            self.bar_list[i] = self.__default_bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you note, MyPy is entirely right to complain about this one. You're explicitly saying "This will not contain None" when you've told it on just the previous line "Watch out because this may contain None." What you're hoping to express is "This (eventually) won't contain None" but that just isn't really MyPy's style. If you want it to be done cleanly, the type has to be valid at the moment of creation. Only then will MyPy be able to help ensure it stays valid.

I'd just do this one with a list comprehension. Something like

```
self.bar_list: List[Bar] = [
    b if b is not None else self.__default_bar() for b in bar_list
]
```

Although this means making a fresh list, I'd urge you to see that as a plus rather than a minus. It's generally considered very poor form to mutate inputs to your function unless that is the sole and express purpose of that function.